# NumberFormatException with IntEditTextPreference

Tags: android, preference

In my android application, I'm using a class called 'IntEditTextPreference'. This class is used when I want a user to introduce a preference as an integer.

But it has a problem. When the user leaves the field empty and press "ok", an NumberFormatException is thrown.

What could I do to avoid the user to press "ok" when the field is empty?

Thanks!

```
public class IntEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference
{

   public IntEditTextPreference(Context context)
   {
           super(context);
   }

   public IntEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {
       super(context, attrs);
   }

   public IntEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
   {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   @Override
   protected String getPersistedString(String defaultReturnValue)
   {
        return String.valueOf(getPersistedInt(-1));
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean persistString(String value)
   {
       return persistInt(Integer.valueOf(value));
   }
```

}

Comment: where is persistInt method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably still have a try/catch block around it to catch `NumberFormatException`. But there are many ways to do this. One way is you can use the buttons `setClickable` method to `false` and then true when the text is not null and is integer using `onTextChangedListener`. Or you could simply let it be clickable but check for empty string or non-integer when the button is clicked and use a warning message toast/alert/label to let the user know they have incorrect field before allowing the button to do anything else. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I've done it. In the constructor of the EditTextPreference I've created a EditTextWatcher and associated to the EditText of the preference `getEditText().addTextChangedListener(watcher)`. Then, inside the watcher, I check if the field is empty or not, and depending on it, I disable o enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you are using a browser-based-application, you would use *JavaScript/AJAX* to display a button when the input is valid. This is already handled at client side.
To avoid the `NumberFormatException,` simply add a `try`-`catch`-block around the `Integer.valueOf(value)` statement.

Basically it depends on your client-framework. There might be better framework-specific solutions. Which one do you use?

Comment: Doh... that would explain the Android tag. Sry, was currently deep in Web-based dev and couldn't realize that there may be sth different.